# How to map a nested list using ModelMapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm facing a problem, I'm using ModelMapper to map objects but I find myself unable to tackle this issue using custom mappings.

Here's my source model:

```java
public class UserSource {
    
    private List<IdentitySource> identities;
    
}

public class IdentitySource {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
}
```

And here's my destination model:

```java
public class UserDestination {
    
    private List<NestedIdentityDestination> nestedIdentities;
    
}

public class NestedIdentityDestination {
    
    private IdentityDestination identity;
    
}

public class IdentityDestination {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this using ModelMapper please?

Comment: `Identity` = `IdentitySource`?

Comment: Right, I edited my question and answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research and experimenting, I've figured it out. I needed to use a mix of converter and type mapping.

Here's my solution:

```java
Converter<List<IdentitySource>, List<NestedIdentityDestination>> convertIdentities = new AbstractConverter<>() {
    protected List<NestedIdentityDestination> convert(List<IdentitySource> source) {
        return source.stream().map(identity -> {
            NestedIdentityDestination nestedIdentity = new NestedIdentityDestination();
            nestedIdentity.setIdentity(modelMapper.map(identity, IdentityDestination.class));
            return nestedIdentity;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
};

modelMapper.typeMap(UserSource.class, UserDestination.class)
        .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(convertIdentities)
                .map(UserSource::getIdentities, UserDestination::setNestedIdentities));
```

Hope this helps other people facing the same problem.

Comment: Excellent solution, I scoured the internet and couldn't find a practical example! I was almost giving up! Thank you very much !

Comment: I'm glad this SO question/answer found some use somewhere else :)